# VHDL Can't infer register for " " at " " because it does not hold it's value outside the clock edge

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I am not very good at programming vhdl and I am running up to this error:

```
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[0]" at Receiver.vhd(123) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[1]" at Receiver.vhd(123) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[2]" at Receiver.vhd(123) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[3]" at Receiver.vhd(123) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[4]" at Receiver.vhd(123) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[5]" at Receiver.vhd(123) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[6]" at Receiver.vhd(123) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[7]" at Receiver.vhd(123) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[8]" at Receiver.vhd(106) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[9]" at Receiver.vhd(106) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[10]" at Receiver.vhd(106) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[11]" at Receiver.vhd(106) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[12]" at Receiver.vhd(106) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[13]" at Receiver.vhd(106) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[14]" at Receiver.vhd(106) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[15]" at Receiver.vhd(106) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[16]" at Receiver.vhd(89) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[17]" at Receiver.vhd(89) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "Current_Number_32[18]" at Receiver.vhd(89) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
```

code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity Receiver is
    Port ( SYS_CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
          RST : in STD_LOGIC;
          DATA_ACK : out STD_LOGIC;
             DATA_VALID : in STD_LOGIC;
             DATA_BUS_8 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
             DIGIT_1 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
             DIGIT_2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
             DIGIT_3 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
             DIGIT_4 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
             DIGIT_5 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
             DIGIT_6 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
             DIGIT_7 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
             DIGIT_8 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0));
end Receiver;

architecture Behavioral of Receiver is
    signal Current_Number_32 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    
    function BitsToDisplay (Bits : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0) := (others => '0')) return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is
        variable DisplayBits : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
    begin
        case Bits is
            when "0000" => DisplayBits :=   "1111110";
            when "0001" => DisplayBits :=   "0110000";
            when "0010" => DisplayBits :=   "1101110";
            when "0011" => DisplayBits :=   "1111001";
            when "0100" => DisplayBits :=   "0110011";
            when "0101" => DisplayBits :=   "1011011";
            when "0110" => DisplayBits :=   "1011111";
            when "0111" => DisplayBits :=   "1110000";
            when "1000" => DisplayBits :=   "1111111";
            when "1001" => DisplayBits :=   "1111101";
            when "1010" => DisplayBits :=   "1110111";
            when "1011" => DisplayBits :=   "0011111";
            when "1100" => DisplayBits :=   "1001111";
            when "1101" => DisplayBits :=   "0111101";
            when "1110" => DisplayBits :=   "1001111";
            when "1111" => DisplayBits :=   "1000111";
            when  others => DisplayBits := "0000001";
        end case;
        return DisplayBits;
    end function;
    
    
begin
    Communication : process (SYS_CLK,RST,DATA_ACK,DATA_VALID,DATA_BUS_8)
        variable Section_1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        variable Section_2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        variable Section_3 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        variable Section_4 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        variable Current_Section : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        variable Stage : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    begin
        if (RST = '1') then
            DATA_ACK <= '0';
            Current_Number_32 <= (others => '0');
            Section_1 := (others => '0');
            Section_2 := (others => '0');
            Section_3 := (others => '0');
            Section_4 := (others => '0');
            Current_Section := (others => '0');
            Stage := (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(SYS_CLK)  then
                if (Current_Section = "00") then
                    if (Stage = "00") and rising_edge(DATA_VALID) then
                        Section_1 := DATA_BUS_8;
                        Stage := "01";
                    end if;
                    
                    if (Stage = "01") and (DATA_ACK = '1') then
                        DATA_ACK <= '0';
                        Stage := "00";
                        Current_Section := "01";
                    end if;
                    
                    if (Stage = "01") and falling_edge(DATA_VALID) then
                        DATA_ACK <= '1';
                    end if;                 
                end if;
                
                if (Current_Section = "01") then
                    if (Stage = "00") and rising_edge(DATA_VALID) then
                        Section_2 := DATA_BUS_8;
                        Stage := "01";
                    end if;
                    
                    if (Stage = "01") and (DATA_ACK = '1') then
                        DATA_ACK <= '0';
                        Stage := "00";
                        Current_Section := "10";
                    end if;
                    
                    if (Stage = "01") and falling_edge(DATA_VALID) then
                        DATA_ACK <= '1';
                    end if;                 
                end if;
                
                if (Current_Section = "10") then
                    if (Stage = "00") and rising_edge(DATA_VALID) then
                        Section_3 := DATA_BUS_8;
                        Stage := "01";
                    end if;
                    
                    if (Stage = "01") and (DATA_ACK = '1') then
                        DATA_ACK <= '0';
                        Stage := "00";
                        Current_Section := "11";
                    end if;
                    
                    if (Stage = "01") and falling_edge(DATA_VALID) then
                        DATA_ACK <= '1';
                    end if;                 
                end if;
                
                if (Current_Section = "11") then
                    if (Stage = "00") and rising_edge(DATA_VALID) then
                        Section_4 := DATA_BUS_8;
                        Stage := "01";
                    end if;
                    
                    if (Stage = "01") and (DATA_ACK = '1') then
                        Current_Number_32(31 downto 24) <= Section_1;
                        Current_Number_32(23 downto 16) <= Section_2;
                        Current_Number_32(15 downto 8) <= Section_3;
                        Current_Number_32(7 downto 0) <= Section_4;
                        DATA_ACK <= '0';
                        Stage := "00";
                        Current_Section := "00";
                    end if;
                    
                    if (Stage = "01") and falling_edge(DATA_VALID) then
                        DATA_ACK <= '1';
                    end if;                 
                end if;             
        end if;
    end process Communication;
    
    Display : process (SYS_CLK,RST,DIGIT_1,DIGIT_2,DIGIT_3,DIGIT_4,DIGIT_5,DIGIT_6,DIGIT_7,DIGIT_8)
    begin
        if (RST = '1') then
            DIGIT_8 <= (others => '0');
            DIGIT_7 <= (others => '0');
            DIGIT_6 <= (others => '0');
            DIGIT_5 <= (others => '0');
            DIGIT_4 <= (others => '0');
            DIGIT_3 <= (others => '0');
            DIGIT_2 <= (others => '0');
            DIGIT_1 <= (others => '0');
        else
            DIGIT_8 <= BitsToDisplay(Current_Number_32(3 downto 0));
            DIGIT_7 <= BitsToDisplay(Current_Number_32(7 downto 4));
            DIGIT_6 <= BitsToDisplay(Current_Number_32(11 downto 8));
            DIGIT_5 <= BitsToDisplay(Current_Number_32(15 downto 12));
            DIGIT_4 <= BitsToDisplay(Current_Number_32(19 downto 16));
            DIGIT_3 <= BitsToDisplay(Current_Number_32(23 downto 20));
            DIGIT_2 <= BitsToDisplay(Current_Number_32(27 downto 24));
            DIGIT_1 <= BitsToDisplay(Current_Number_32(31 downto 28));
        end if; 
    end process Display;
    
end Behavioral;
```

Can anyone please explain what I am doing wrong here?
I have added this code as a block to a block diagram with two other codes but before I did that compiling revealed no errors.
This code does not need to run on an actual fpga because this is a school assignment so I only need to simulate it. does that remove this error?

Comment: What tool are you using? With a quick look, the errors look odd because it is clearly registers that should be inferred. I would recommend you do not use any variables though and only use signals. They behave differently to each other and variables can create different circuits purely based on the order of code in a process. Hence as a beginner, I would recommend never using variables.

Comment: This could have something to do with the variables. Can you try to refactor all of those stage variables to signals? Resetting them won't do anything as well

Answer (score 0):

Trim your sensitivity list down to this:

process (SYS_CLK,RST)

You don't want to execute the process when input data changes. Only when the clock or reset changes.